# Error usando<Provider> en React Native + Jest y Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, react-native, test, react-redux, jest

Estoy intentando realizar un test de un componente de React Native con Jest + React Library.

Según documentaciones, he creado un apartado de test-utils.js para manejar renderizado y otras necesidades que sean más custom. En este caso, un renderizado con el provider de Redux.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {render} from '@testing-library/react-native';

import rootReducer from '../redux/reducers';
import store from '../redux/store';

function renderWithProviders(
  ui,
  {preloadedState = {}, _store = store, ...renderOptions} = {},
) {
  function Wrapper({children}) {
    return <Provider store={_store}>{children}</Provider>;
  }

  return render(ui, {wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions});
}

// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react-native';

// override render method
export {renderWithProviders as render};
```

Luego en el test, simplemente intento hacer un test básico en el que si paso datos vacíos a la prop, renderiza una view diciendo que no hay nada:

```js
it('renders correctly with empty patient list', () => {
    const patientList = [];
    const {getByText} = render(<FinishStop patientList={patientList} />);

    // Verificar que se muestra el texto indicando que no hay pacientes
    const noPatientsText = getByText('No hay pacientes');

    expect(noPatientsText).toBeDefined();
  });
```

El problema lleva al ejecutar el test, ya que salta error y dice:

```
 console.error
  Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

  Check the render method of `Wrapper`.
      at children (C:\Users\pesua\Workspace\siportAndroidTablet\src\utils\test-utils.js:12:21)

  11 | ) {
  12 |   function Wrapper({children}) {
> 13 |     return <Provider store={_store}>{children}</Provider>;
     |            ^
  14 |   }
  15 |
  16 |   return render(ui, {wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions});

  at printWarning (node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-runtime.development.js:87:30)
  at error (node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-runtime.development.js:61:7)
  at jsxWithValidation (node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-runtime.development.js:1244:7)
  at jsxWithValidationDynamic (node_modules/react/cjs/react-jsx-runtime.development.js:1301:12)
  at Wrapper (src/utils/test-utils.js:13:12)
  at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6351:18)
  at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:9855:13)
  at beginWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11312:16)
  at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15811:12)
  at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15745:5)
  at renderRootSync (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15717:7)
  at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15422:20)
  at flushSyncCallbacks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2597:22)
  at flushActQueue (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:2667:24)
  at Object.act (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:2521:11)
  at act (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/src/render-act.ts:13:16)
  at render (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/src/render.tsx:48:33)
  at renderWithProviders (src/utils/test-utils.js:16:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/FinishStop/index.test.js:60:11)

console.error
  The above error occurred in the <Wrapper> component:

      at children (C:\Users\pesua\Workspace\siportAndroidTablet\src\utils\test-utils.js:12:21)

  Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
  Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

  14 |   }
  15 |
> 16 |   return render(ui, {wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions});
     |                ^
  17 | }
  18 |
  19 | // re-export everything

  at logCapturedError (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:8661:23)
  at update.callback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:8694:5)
  at callCallback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:4092:12)
  at commitUpdateQueue (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:4113:9)
  at commitLayoutEffectOnFiber (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:13232:13)
  at commitLayoutMountEffects_complete (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14330:9)
  at commitLayoutEffects_begin (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14316:7)
  at commitLayoutEffects (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14301:3)
  at commitRootImpl (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:16062:5)
  at commitRoot (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15933:5)
  at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15454:3)
  at flushSyncCallbacks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2597:22)
  at flushActQueue (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:2667:24)
  at Object.act (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:2521:11)
  at act (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/src/render-act.ts:13:16)
  at render (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/src/render.tsx:48:33)
  at renderWithProviders (src/utils/test-utils.js:16:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/FinishStop/index.test.js:60:11)

FinishStop › renders correctly with empty patient list
                                                                                                                                                                                       
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                       
Check the render method of `Wrapper`.                                                                                                                                                  

  14 |   }
  15 |
> 16 |   return render(ui, {wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions});
     |                ^
  17 | }
  18 |
  19 | // re-export everything

  at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:17518:17)
  at createFiberFromElement (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:17544:15)
  at reconcileSingleElement (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:5813:23)
  at reconcileChildFibers (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:5871:35)
  at reconcileChildren (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:9096:28)
  at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:9915:5)
  at beginWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11312:16)
  at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15811:12)
  at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15745:5)
  at renderRootSync (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15717:7)
  at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15422:20)
  at flushSyncCallbacks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2597:22)
  at flushActQueue (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:2667:24)
  at Object.act (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:2521:11)
  at act (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/src/render-act.ts:13:16)
  at render (node_modules/@testing-library/react-native/src/render.tsx:48:33)
  at renderWithProviders (src/utils/test-utils.js:16:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/FinishStop/index.test.js:60:11)
```

Llevo un buen rato intentando descubrir por qué me está fallando el Provider, como si estuviera mal importado, pero en realidad no lo está y no sé por dónde seguir con este error.

Actualización:
Por mucho que reviso, parece ser que a la hora de realizar tests, Provider es undefined, y la importación es correcta.